# Форма деепричастия «переждя»

Tags: грамотная-речь, окончания, деепричастия, словоизменение

Скажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли употреблено деепричастие в данном предложении?
*Приятно наслаждаться прохладой, **переждя** жару.*

В справочных источниках есть расхождения относительно того, к какому виду относится деепричастие "переждя", и в связи с этим не ясно, согласуется ли оно с видом инфинитива. Если нет, то является ли такое употребление неправильным?
Глагол "переждать" относится к совершенному виду и имеет деепричастную форму "переждав". Соответствующий глагол в несовершенном виде "пережидать" образует деепричастие "пережидая".

Но некоторые глаголы совершенного вида также могут иметь деепричастия оканчивающиеся на *-я*, например, *увидев/увидя*.
Если глагол "переждать" принадлежит к глаголам с двойной формой деепричастия (*переждав/переждя*), то существует ли какая-то разница в их значении и употреблении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта форма не является правильной, потому что она не звучит и не используется.

Правильно так:
*Приятно наслаждаться прохладой, **переждав** жару.*  || Тоже деепричастие прошедшего времени.

Все корректные формы смотрите здесь (вашей среди них нет):
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/переждать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Ни одного примера с "переждя" в Нацкорпусе, а с "переждав" есть много примеров: [вот они](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2).

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Я согласна с тем, что форма "переждав" звучит правильней, но смущает большое количество случаев употребления формы "переждя" у советских и современных авторов, особенно поэтов. Даже в поэтическом корпусе по вашей ссылке выдается результат с этой формой. А также она, например, встречается в "Литературной коллекции" Солженицына. Означает ли это, что в настоящее время в норму употребления входит параллельная форма, ранее не включенная в словари?

Comment: Дело в том, что стихи ограничены рифмой и ритмом, и там часто идут на разного рода нарушения в связи с этим. Даже в правилах иногда указывается, что в поэзии встречается такое-то отклонение от нормы. 1 результат в Нацкорпусе обычно означает ошибку. Эта форма существует в том плане, что носитель языка может её образовать, но она неудачна по звучанию, как и "победя", и не рекомендуется к употреблению. Кстати, большое спасибо здесь — галочка возле ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Форма ***переждя́*** нечасто, конечно же, но используется. И звучит, мне кажется, звучит...
Другое дело — является ли правильной?

I. Присутствует она у А. А. Зализняка (полная акцентуированная парадигма: см. [здесь](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_forms/46827/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) и [здесь](https://rus-forms.slovaronline.com/46827-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)).

II. Вот что о ней (о таких деепричастиях) говорится в справочнике по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию:

> **4.** В парах ***высунув — высуня*** (ср.: *бежать **высуня** язык*); ***положив — положа*** (ср.: ***положа** руку на сердце*), ***разинув — разиня*** (ср.: *слушать **разиня** рот*), ***скрепив — скрепя*** (ср.: *согласиться **скрепя** сердце*), ***сломив — сломя*** (ср.: *броситься **сломя** голову*), ***спустив — спустя*** (ср.: *работать **спустя** рукава*) и т. п. **вторые формы являются устарелыми**, но сохраняются в устойчивых фразеологических выражениях.

III. Вы правы, есть она в [поэтическом корпусе](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&mode=poetic&nodia=1&req=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8F&sort=i_grtagging&text=lexform):

Лучше так вот шагать всю жизнь,
Чем, грозу **переждя**,
Вслед за теми послушно плестись,
Кто прячется от дождя.
[Б. А. Богатков. Сквозь ливень («Мелькнули молнии несколько раз…») (1940)]

В действительности же стихотворение имеет такой вид (это говорит о том, что не нужно *слепо* цитировать Нацкорпус; я всегда проверяю):

> Лучше так вот шагать всю жизнь,
> Чем, грозу **переждя**,
> Вслед за теми послушно плестись,
> Кто прошел сквозь стрелы дождя

> И не видит душою праздною,
> Как во всей красоте и силе
> Сверкает и свищет полотнище красное,
> Омытое ливнем от будничной пыли.

Есть и другие известные поэты, использующие "переждя".

*Осень, ветровая и рябая,

явится, немного **переждя**,

по сгоревшим листьям барабаня

нахлыстом ядреного дождя.*
Н. М. Якушев. На исходе северное лето...

*Увидишь, тучу **переждя**,

Как полетит с ограды птица,

И с каплей сладкого дождя

Слеза твоя ко мне скатится.*
Исай Шейнис. Лети, душа

IV. Устарелая это форма, особенная, но право на использование, думаю, она имеет — в особых контекстах, конечно, не каждодневно.

[Формы деепричастий](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091256.html#id-40%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%C2%A7177%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9)
[Им не воздвигли мраморной плиты. Стихи поэтов, погибших на войне](https://books.google.ee/books?id=03MREAAAQBAJ&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8F%22&source=bl&ots=8OSPKxpmtV&sig=ACfU3U0_Rw2vS36A19v_dewdE2ub2zL7bw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI6p20xMP0AhWFi8MKHeRfDbQ4HhDoAXoECBcQAw#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8F%22&f=false)

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: Присутствует она у А. А. Зализняка…_ === В его словаре такой формы, по-моему, нет. Есть только _переждав_ и _переждавши_.

Comment: У меня нет печатного издания. Но в двух интернет-ресурсах слово имеется (посмотрите ссылки).

Comment: Ссылки смотрел. Но… Давайте, я лучше сейчас сделаю несколько фотографий из словаря Зализняка и помещу их в этой теме. Выводы сделаете сами.

Comment: *в особых контекстах, конечно* — только в стихах? Или какие такие особые контексты?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо комментария (в продолжение разговора с Риммой Михайловой) – два фото из «Грамматического словаря» Зализняка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]